# How to set up a captive portal in Linksys WRT120N or TL-WR840N?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router, captive-portal

How can I set up a captive portal with the following brands Linksys WRT120N or TL-WR840N?

I own this two routers and I want to set up a captive portal, doesn't matter in which router. Do I need to flash it, if so which firmware, DDWRT or OpenWRT? What is the most relevant difference.

If captive portals are just `http` redirects, then why not all routers support it?

Comment: You will have to choose DDWRT or OpenWRT based on your devices compatibility. We can’t make a recommendation either way as questions seeking software recommendations are out of scope. So which one supports your device?